# Excel syntax error while using substitute [Sharepoint]

Tags: excel, sharepoint, substitution

So I was working on SharePoint and I created a Excel which contains a column called "Temp" and I need to substitute every "a" in the column "Temp" with "b" but it tells me I have syntax error?

Code:

```
=SUBSTITUTE([Temp],"a","b")
```

Comment: Your local/language version of Excel may require ";" instead of ",". Try typing the formula into Excel itself and see how it corrects you.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I'm pretty sure that it requires "," because other functions like concatenate works with ","